# Angular-cli component generator generate additional files

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Is there a way to override the default behavior of the

```
ng generate component
```

command?  In addition to the files that this command creates by default, I am wanting to have it generate a nested folder and several files within that folder inside the component that is created.

Comment: did you find anything?

Comment: Not yet.  I will update if I find anything.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Updated it a bit to hopefully clarify what I am trying to do a little better.

Answer (score -1):

Additional files are generated using additional commands. You can find a reference to it on https://github.com/angular/angular-cli

> You can find all possible blueprints in the table below:
>
> ```
> +-----------+---------------------------------+
> | Scaffold  | Usage                           |
> +-----------+---------------------------------+
> | Component | ng g component my-new-component |
> +-----------+---------------------------------+
> | Directive | ng g directive my-new-directive |
> +-----------+---------------------------------+
> | Pipe      | ng g pipe my-new-pipe           |
> +-----------+---------------------------------+
> | Service   | ng g service my-new-service     |
> +-----------+---------------------------------+
> | Class     | ng g class my-new-class         |
> +-----------+---------------------------------+
> | Interface | ng g interface my-new-interface |
> +-----------+---------------------------------+
> | Enum      | ng g enum my-new-enum           |
> +-----------+---------------------------------+
> | Module    | ng g module my-module           |
> +-----------+---------------------------------+
> ```

Comment: that's not a solution, he's asking to customize a command not to use more to satisfy the need. Wondering the same

Comment: As the previous comment said, I am looking to customize what the generate command generates.  Ex, when I do ng generate component I want it to create some additional files.

Comment: @Cruil Can you clarify what additional files?